# Java cube program having issues on second and third instances

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

This is my program; the point of it is to take a side value from the user and output the surface area and volume. I am checking for incorrect input into the program, like inputting a letter instead of a number. It works when I only use one instance but on the second and third instances I receive an error. I am not sure what my issue is here.

```
import java.util.InputMismatchException;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;

public class cube

{
    private double side;

public double getLength(){

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

while(true){
    try{
        System.out.println("Please enter an integer: ");
        side = sc.nextDouble();
        break;

    }
    catch(InputMismatchException a){

        System.err.println("\nWrong character");
        sc.next();
        continue;
    }
}   
    sc.close();
    return side;
}

/*
 * Calculate the Surface Are of the cube base on the user side input
 */
public double calculateSurfaceArea(){

    return 6 * side * side;
}

/*
 * Calculate the volume of the cube base on the user side input
 */
public double calculateVolume(){

    return side * side * side;
}


/**
 * main() -- creates an instance of Cube and tests it
 */
public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException
{

    // HINT: input the side from the keyboard and check for errors and exceptions
    cube cube1 = new cube();

    // Print the test results
    System.out.println("\nSide length of cube1 is " + cube1.getLength());
    System.out.println("Surface Area of cube1 is " + cube1.calculateSurfaceArea ());
    System.out.println("Volume of cube1 is " +  cube1.calculateVolume());
    // Hint - add two more cube instances

    cube cube2 = new cube();

    // Print the test results
    System.out.println("\nSide length of cube2 is " + cube2.getLength());
    System.out.println("Surface Area of cube2 is " + cube2.calculateSurfaceArea ());
    System.out.println("Volume of cube2 is " +  cube2.calculateVolume());

    cube cube3 = new cube();

    // Print the test results
    System.out.println("\nSide length of cube3 is " + cube3.getLength());
    System.out.println("Surface Area of cube3 is " + cube3.calculateSurfaceArea ());
    System.out.println("Volume of cube3 is " +  cube3.calculateVolume());
} // main() } // Cube
```

The error is:

```
 Please enter an integer: 
    java.util.NoSuchElementException
        at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.Scanner.next(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.Scanner.nextDouble(Unknown Source)
        at folder.name.........(cube.java:18)
        at folder.name.........(cube.java:68)
```

Comment: @john3136 thanks for that feedback I will change the order on that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're closing the `System.in` stream here:

```
sc.close();
```

This *prevents* all other instances from ever getting access to that stream and reading from it, which is why you're getting the `NoSuchElementException`.  Remove that line and you should be good.

As a general rule, ***never close System streams (in, out, or err)***.  Other parts of your application may depend on them, if they're closed, you'll get this cryptic exception every time.

Comment: This works perfect. I can't believe it was something that small. Thanks!